# Can't select item in select2 because of multiple select lower down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-select2

When i open #s1 i can't select the options 2 & 3. When i click on them the cursor goes into the #s2.
How can i fix this bug?

I thought that it could be something with z-index, but i tried and it didn't help.

```
<form action="" class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" data-ltext=""></label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select name="s1" id="s1" class="form-control">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" data-ltext=""></label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" data-ltext=""></label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select name="s2" id="s2" class="form-control" multiple>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#s1').select2();
        $('#s2').select2();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine to me. Perhaps it is the order in which you've imported the `<link>` and `<script>` tags that's causing the issue?

I haven't really done anything here except for using the code that you've provided. I had some issues where I accidentally kept the links for select2 before jQuery, and that caused some errors, so it might be that you have a similar issue

```js
$(function() {
  $('#s1').select2();
  $('#s2').select2();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form action="" class="form-horizontal">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" data-ltext=""></label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <select name="s1" id="s1" class="form-control">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" data-ltext=""></label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" data-ltext=""></label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <select name="s2" id="s2" class="form-control" multiple>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer i solved the problem with z-index. The Element with the multiple select had a much bigger z-index than the others. I removed this and now it works fine.